# UK child travelling to Dublin on an expired passport

Tags: air-travel, uk-citizens, dublin

My daughters UK passport has expired (in December) and she needs to travel to Dublin from London by air. Can she still use it as I understand UK citizens only need photo ID to travel to Dublin. Thanks

Comment: Does she have any currently valid official photo ID? Driver's license? If not, the issue is whether both the airline and the Irish officials will accept an expired ID.

Comment: She's 11 and doesn't have a drivers license. what other typical photo ID do children have? Maybe school ID? Don't know if that would be accepted.

Comment: If you have time before her travel, get that passport renewed using the fast track service mentioned in the answer. Otherwise, have her take everything she has that is somewhat official and has her photo, including her expired passport and school ID. Have a backup plan, such as a parent staying at the airport until her flight has left, in case it does not work.

Answer (score 2):

A British citizen doesn't need a passport to enter Ireland - you do however require valid photo ID *that proves nationality* and some sea and air carriers will only accept passports.

If you're planning on using a passport as proof of identity/nationality then it needs to be valid for at least the [planned duration of the stay in Ireland](https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/ireland/entry-requirements):

> Passport validity
>   If you’re using a passport to enter Ireland, it should be valid for the proposed duration of your stay; you don’t need any additional period of validity on your passport beyond this.

So it would appear that you're going to need an alternative form of ID - e.g. Driver's License. And then it's going to be down to what forms the carrier will accept. If she needs a passport then the fastest way you can renew a Child passport is with the [1 week fast track service](https://www.gov.uk/get-a-passport-urgently/1-week-fast-track-service),  as you can't do the same-day ones for Child renewals (only for adults).